# Why does WKF not allow Mae geri (Front Snap Kick) and Yoko geri (Side Kick)?

Tags: karate

I am a Shotokan Karate practitioner and I have good control over my kick. However,  even with that I am not doing well under WKF sparring because these two kicks are disallowed. I find them very effective as they go to the centre of the body and are hard to block.

Although most of semi contact sports allow them like TKD, Wu Shu etc…, WKF does not allow them. *Why is that?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where did you get the idea that these techniques are disallowed?  Not only are they allowed, but they score well for jodan - and may be trapped.

Here, Article 8, which describes prohibited actions, no mention of any specific technique is mentioned - only prohibited targets (groin, throat, etc)

[KATA AND KUMITE COMPETITION RULES
REVISION 9.0
EFFECTIVE FROM 1.1.2015](https://www.wkf.net/pdf/wkf-competition-rules-version9-2015-en.pdf)

**EDIT**: Added a more updated document, just released:

[KATA AND KUMITE COMPETITION RULES
EFFECTIVE FROM 1.1.2018](https://www.wkf.net/pdf/WKFCompetitionRules2018.pdf)

And in it, still no mention of specific banned techniques - only banned targets.

Also, in your comment, you mention that a class of techniques (eg, "curved") would fall under a category of prohibited action.  This is partly true: but it applies to **every single** technique.  The idea behind the rule:

> Techniques, which by their nature, cannot be controlled for the
>   safety of the opponent and dangerous and uncontrolled attacks [*sic*, are Category 2 prohibited behaviors]

...is for contestant safety.  In other words, if you can't control a punch... don't punch.  If you can't control a front kick... don't use the front kick.  And so on.  If your instructor has evaluated you, and found that your kicks are not well controlled, s/he may well tell you that, for purposes of an upcoming competition, you "should not" (not "cannot") use those techniques.

That is fine: you are not banned from it, and there's no rules against it; rather, you are being told that temporarily, you shouldn't use it because you can't control it.  If you use the technique your instructor has told you not to use, and yet it lands safely, then no problem.  Similarly, if your instructor doesn't tell you not to punch, because s/he thinks you control them well, and then you punch your opponent in an uncontrolled way possibly injuring him, guess what?  You get a warning or point deduction.  It's not the technique, it's the result of the technique.

That is the only reason I can think of why you might have gotten the idea that the technique, per se, has been banned.  It hasn't.

Comment: . Techniques, which by their nature, cannot be controlled for the safety of the opponent and
dangerous and uncontrolled attacks. are prohibited though.  Does it come under this?  Apparantly from the karate I have done curved punches come under this.

Comment: That would be an interpretation on the rule which should be made by coaches and officials.  On the other hand, a front kick and side kick are hardly considered curved techniques, where round house and crescent kicks are unequivocally ARE.  The rules say anything goes, as long as there's control, correct technique, and other criteria.

Comment: I think in India its widely wrong interpreted. although I did not able to access the link its leads to 404 error. because I did try to use that and its not even connect fully (Yoko geri) and I has been warned by chokaku. with inclusion straight kicks and curved punches.

Comment: @Wigwam how could any Techniques have nature that it could not be controlled? by means of that is it like techniques that hard to defend or something. because I think that Mar Geri and Yoko Geri both are controllable but less defendable compare to Other kicks.

Comment: I can't help with the 404, I can access the link myself.  You may be restricted from viewing PDF files, but that is a technical issue outside the scope here.

Comment: As to how a technique can have nature that it cannot be controlled, it's not the technique that is the problem: it is the person.  If you can't throw mae geri properly, but I can, then you should not use mae geri.  Just this past weekend, I officiated at a tournament which saw several uncontrolled techniques - all punches - and had to warn them that they were uncontrolled.

Comment: @Wingwam i am now able to access the link and now from that i did aware that they do allow this with less force but not to face as it will contact on center part of face that is injury prone and crucial part so they do not allow this kick on face and groin and like other below belt parts. thanks for the link.